# Java (ajax) communicate with external PHP (Cordova in VS)

Tags: java, php, html, ajax, cordova

I'm creating a cross-Platform application in Cordova using Visual Studio.
I need to communicate with an external web-server, which does the processing to my MSSQL server.

In the client side I have an *Index.html* file and it uses an external javascript file *index.js*.

On the server-side I have several PHP pages. Every single one has a different purpose.

**Index.html:**

```
<form id="sendmsg" method="POST" action="http://www.somesite.com/.../processingmsg.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <p class="darkbg">* verplichte velden</p>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="darkbg">Naam</label>
                <input class="form-control" onkeyup="lengtecheck()" type="text" name="naam" id="naam" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="darkbg">Leeftijd</label>
                <input class="form-control" onkeyup="lengtecheck()" type="text" name="leeftijd" id="leeftijd" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="darkbg">Telefoon</label>
                <input class="form-control" onkeyup="lengtecheck()" type="text" name="telefoon" id="telefoon" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="darkbg">Email</label>
                <input class="form-control" onkeyup="lengtecheck()" type="email" name="email" id="email" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="darkbg">*ES Code</label>
                <input class="form-control" onkeyup="lengtecheck()" type="text" name="escode" id="escode" required />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="darkbg">*Bericht</label>
                <p class="darkbg" id="tekens">0/100</p>
                <textarea class="form-control" onkeyup="lengtecheck()" rows="7" id="msg" name="msg" cols="20" placeholder="Typ hier uw bericht..." maxlength="100" required></textarea>
            </div>
            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Send" id="Send">
            <input action="action" class="btn btn-danger" type="button" onclick="window.history.back();" value="Back">
        </form>
```

How can I make it so that when the user clicks the *Send* button, processingmsg.php will process everything and on success, trigger a javascript function on the client side?

**Additional question**: Can I return a set of results (e.g table, dropdown values, etc.) with this?

Comment: PHP is server side code, it can not trigger anything on the client. As soon as your form is submitted it will destroy the current context for HTML/CSS/Javascript. Meaning no objects exist anymore. You should use Ajax for this. An Ajax call will call the PHP code without refreshing and thus destroying the current page and it can run a callback after getting the response from the PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

Don't rely on the browser's default `<form action="...">` handling to do this. Instead use AJAX (XHR). HTML5Rocks has a great example: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/#toc-send-formdata

Then, you can parse the response as needed and update your DOM as necessary. I suggest returning JSON, since you can use `JSON.parse(response)` to get a useful JavaScript object that's easy to work with.

Tip: Use HTTPS and SSL/TLS. And don't forget to whitelist your host and set up your `content-security-policy` meta tag appropriately.

Comment: how can you catch a while response then??

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking in your comment. Please rephrase.

Comment: my php does a While loop.

How can i catch that with AJAX